# Parallax JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нужно написать **parallax на jquery с нуля**. Можете скинуть какие-нибудь обучающие видео или статьи (желательно на русском, но английский чуть что тоже пойдёт)? Буду очень благодарен! 
P.s ( В гугле чёт не нашёл, может потому что руки не из того места )

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I98ojKzYpew&t=365s

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/142137/

Comment: если руки не из того места, может и не стоит самому с нуля писать?)

Comment: @stasovlas, пусть пишет. Учиться же когда-то нужно :)

Comment: @Yuri твоя правд

Answer (score 0):

Пользуйся на здоровье) Когда то сам задался таким вопросом. И целый плейлист накопился на данную тему.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLaiED-E5hBXEvgLTZNZU0DIZG_sxOi09B